# Limits of definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am a bit confused about the limits of definite integral. 

I just wanted to confirm this $$ \int_a^b f(x)d(g(x))= \int_{g^{-1}(a)}^{g^{-1}(b)}f(x)g'(x)dx $$
right? I mean the limits would change g(x) we bring it out of the differential term? My professor did not do this in a sum in class. The primary doubt here is what the limits are of. I believe the limits are of the variable inside the d() thing while my friend says its always the variable x. Can someone please confirm who is correct and give some example for a better understanding.

PS:Sorry for the sub-standard question on maths SE.

Comment: The limits you have right now are the correct ones do not worry.

Comment: The correct limit is $$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dg(x) = \int_{a}^{b} f(x) g'(x) \, dx.$$ The limits are determined by the variables. Notice that the limits can be altered only when you make a substitution or split the integral into parts, and neither is done here.

Comment: The two comments are contradictory! :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Paul Sinclair has said, @Sangchul Lee is correct. Rewriting the integral (and elaborating on Sangchul's comment): $$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\mathrm{d}(g(x))=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\dfrac{\mathrm{d}(g(x))}{\mathrm{d}x}\mathrm{d}x=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g'(x)\mathrm{d}x$$
If there had been some substitution done or splitting of the interval we're integrating over, then perhaps your limits of integration would change.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Stieljes integral. If you look at the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral#Definition) (there are also Lesbegue-Stieljes and Stieljes versions of other integrals, but I'm assuming Riemann here), you see that it is $x$ that is partitioned on the interval $[a,b]$, not $g(x)$.

Thus your friend and Sangchul Lee are correct. If you were doing a change of variables on an ordinary Riemann integral, then you and Ziad Fakhoury would be correct. But for the Stieljes integral, the actual variable being integrated over is $x$ on both sides.